# Keep getting errors trying to use input with mysql

Tags: python, sql, database, search, input

I keep getting this error when i run the function:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)

I am trying to input values taken from another dbs. Any help would be greatly appreciated....

```
def filmByID(results):
    

   sql = "select * from film where filmid in (%s)"
    
    with db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql, (results))
        films = cursor.fetchall()
        for film in films:
            print(film["FilmName"], film["FilmSynopsis"])
```

Comment: you are not showing your sql string. you need to show your sql variable value

Comment: AFAIK, you're not supposed to use parameter replacement with `IN`. If you need to match vs multiple values, then you need to have as many placeholders as values. E.g., `cursor.execute("select * from film where filmid in (%s, %s, %s)", (1, 2, 3))`.

Comment: thanks, what i can do for a placeholder when the number of values is unknow and can vary?

Comment: It's not unknown.  It's unknown at code time, but not at run time.  Create the string of `%s, %s` based on the length of the list/tuple supplied in the `results` parameter.  *(Build the  string in `sql` based on the parameter to the filmByID method.)*

Comment: Is `results` a list, or a tuple?

Comment: It is a tuple, converted from an array

Answer (score 1):

Your question appears to boil down to "how do I repeat the %s the right number of times, to match my `results` parameter?"

```
sql_list = ','.join(['%s'] * len(results))

sql = f"select * from film where filmid in ({sql_list})"
```

This way, if your `results` parameter is, for example, `[1, 2, 3]` then you'll end up with...

```
"select * from film where filmid in (%s,%s,%s)"
```

If the `results` parameter is a list, rather than a tuple, then you may also need to convert it to a tuple...

```
cursor.execute(sql, tuple(results))
```